# Structuring GraphQL types

Tags: graphql

I've run into an issue while trying to extend my API to include a GraphQL endpoint. The application I'm working on is a kind of forum with `Messages`. A message can contain comments of type `Message`. If a message is a comment it has a parent of type `Message`. Simplified, the schema looks like this:

```
type Message {
  id: String
  content: String
  comments: [Message]
  parent: Message
}

type RootQuery {
  message(id: String): Message
  messages: [Message]
}
```

The problem with this schema is that it allows for queries like this:

```
{
  messages {
    comments {
      parent {
        comments {
          parent {
            comments {
              parent {
                id
                content       
              }
            }       
          }
        }   
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that I may want to allow for arbitrarily deep nesting of comments. In that case the following query should be allowed:

```
{
  messages {
    comments {
      comments {
        comments {
          id
          content
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, my question is this: Should I introduce a new type - Comment - to the API that do not know of its parent? Or are there any other ways of restricting this kind of unwanted behaviour?

Also, would the use of a Comment-type prohibit me from using the `fragment messageFields on Message` syntax in my queries? Perhaps this is the time to introduce interfaces to the schema?

Suggestion to a solution if I introduce the type Comment (I have not tried this):

```
interface Message {
  id: String
  content: String
  comments: [Message]
}

type DefaultMessage : Message {
  id: String
  content: String
  comments: [Comment]
  parent: Message
}

type Comment : Message {
  id: String
  content: String
  comments: [Message]
}

type RootQuery {
  message(id: String): Message
  messages: [Message]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else ends up here wondering how to do recursive types in graphql-js, there's a useful hint in graphql-js's code:

```
 * When two types need to refer to each other, or a type needs to refer to
 * itself in a field, you can use a function expression (aka a closure or a
 * thunk) to supply the fields lazily.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 *     var PersonType = new GraphQLObjectType({
 *       name: 'Person',
 *       fields: () => ({
 *         name: { type: GraphQLString },
 *         bestFriend: { type: PersonType },
 *       })
 *     });
 *
 */
```

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/definition.js#L274

Answer (score 0):

> If a message is a comment it has a parent of type Message.

Looks like the `parent` field should be under `type Comment`, not `DefaultMessage`. That still wouldn't prevent a `parent - comments - parent` query but if you're worried about this for a DDOS reason, there are many other types of requests that are difficult to compute, even with REST APIs, and you should have other measures to detect such an attack.

### Recursive nodes

However, you pose a very interesting question with the nested comments. How would you know how many times you need to nest the `comment` in the query to get all nested responses? I don't think it's currently possible with GraphQL to specify recursive objects.

I'd probably go around this limitation by fetching each nested comment one by one (or by X levels at a time) starting from the last comment as the `node`

```
{
  messages {
    comments {
      id
      content
    }
  }
}
```

followed by

```
{
  node(commendId) {
    comment {
      id
      content
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a `depth` attribute of the `Comment` data structure, which should be pretty useful, for example, to limit the max nested depth when the users are posting comments.

So that your problem could be solved like this: in the `resolver` of the `comments` attribute, check the `depth`, return nothing if the `depth` is going illegal, otherwise fetch the comments and return.